# How to get the transferred byte size of a SQL query in qt from an Oracle database?

Tags: c++, sql, oracle, qt

We try to benchmark the database usage for an application written in QT 5 and using an Oracle database.

Counting queries and benchmarking is no problem, but now our supervisor also wants the size in bytes of the received result. At the moment we use only the Qt SQL interface which doesn't give you the received byte count.

Is there a way (preferably within Qt) to get the transferred byte size?

My only idea at the moment is to calculate the bytesize of a row and multiply it with the transferred row count and use it as estimate, but this is more a crutch than a solution...

Thanks in advance,

Kai

Comment: That seems like a fairly pointless metric. It's going to vary with the data in the database. Even if you use a production-like volume of data for testing it still only represents a point in time.

Answer (score 0):

You're assuming that the Oracle driver even reports such information. Does it?

Alas, it doesn't matter. You can easily create a transparent proxy within your application that forwards the data to/from the real database. Then point the driver at the proxy. The proxy will then have access to transfer sizes and can be easily queried about them.